# How can I sculpt this shape?

Tags: sculpting

I'm struggling to sculpt this armchair, especially the blue part (for the red part I made a workaround, creating 3 torus meshes, join with the main mesh and then remesh, still don't know how to sculpt them). I try to use Clay Strip/Inflate and Smooth but the shape just can't be right. Could you give me some suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a cloth + pressure (internal pressure) + pin group + collision objects if you want to add more geometry